# Localytics iOS push cert validation

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, localytics

I'm attempting to setup iOS Push notifications with Localytics. Since I'm switching push providers in revoked my APN certs and created new certs for both Prod and Dev. I'm familiar with this process and have done it a few times.

I now have new certs in Keychain, I export as .p12 and attempt to upload them to Localytics. I'm getting a very generic, "this cert could not be validated with Apple"

I waited a day thinking maybe Apple was doing come caching but I still have this problem.

There is nothing about this in the Localytics KB that I can find. Has anyone seen this error? It's is not a password error, if I enter a bad password the error is different.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on their side. I have the same issue and I let them know a week ago. They suggested me to create certs different ways w/ and w/o password and other weird advices to resolve it.

I wasted time creating certificates thinking that's I'm wrong. But everywhere on other services my certs worked. Lastly they started to keep silence.

Would be great if you wrote them too.

They made me upset

**UPDATE:** The issue has been resolved and everything works fine now.

P.S. Nice platform!

Comment: Can you share some of the workarounds they suggested. Apparently since I'm on the free plan I'm not entitled to support of any kind, including email or even their forum.

Comment: following http://docs.localytics.com/dev/ios.html#enable-push-for-app-id-ios, adding a password to the cert, generating and downloading new certs from apple center, converting .p12 to .pem file and upload it. That's all they suggested. But anyway nothing makes sense.

Comment: yeah thats the docs, not a work around. Did you ever get it working?

Comment: nope, and they stopped answering me. Anyway I'm gonna try to write them again.

Comment: @rjb101 They are on fixing it.

Comment: Awesome. Just tried no love yet but I'll try again later. If you hear any updates please let me know!

Comment: @Sauvage mind updating your answer to add a note that it's been resolved? Sorry for the inconvenience on this one -- it took us longer than it should have to identify the issue on our end at Localytics.